# How do you find the average amount sold of different items per day at different prices?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new in sql and i'm trying to make a query to find out the average amount of products sold per day at different prices for example:  if potatoes were sometimes 2.9/kilo, sometimes 3/kilo and sometimes 3.4/kilo.

I want to show the different prices and the average daily amount sold at each price.I tried making the following query but it does not give me the wanted results:

```
select i.name, od.price, sum(od.Quantity) / count(datepart(d,o.OrderID))
from orderdetails od
join orders o on(o.orderid=od.orderid)
join item i on(i.itemid=od.itemid)
group by i.name, od.price
order by i.name
```

The problem is that if for a certain date there were 3 orders that had apples in it, it will count the orderdate 3 times instead of one because this date is listed 3 times but really i want it should count the number of days that apples were sold at this specific price.

Comment: You need to include the date in the GROUP BY.

Comment: i already tried including the date and it still didn't help.

Comment: is o.OrderID actually a date field? Please provide the structure of your tables and a little sample data to help us figure this out.

Comment: My orderDetails table looks like this:orderID,itemID,Price,Quantity. My orders Table has the following fields:OrderID,OrderDate,DeliveryDaye,DeliveryAddress,LastModified.

Answer (score 0):

```
for average amount sold per day:

select i.name, od.price, avg(od.Quantity)
from orderdetails od
join orders o on(o.orderid=od.orderid)
join item i on(i.itemid=od.itemid)
group by i.name, od.price, datepart(d,o.OrderID)
order by i.name

for number of days per product/price

select i.name, od.price, count(datepart(d,o.OrderID))
from orderdetails od
join orders o on(o.orderid=od.orderid)
join item i on(i.itemid=od.itemid)
group by i.name, od.price
order by i.name
```

Comment: i did this already and it doesn't group it by day. If there were 3 orders one day that include apples and there were 1 order that included apples at another day(at this specific price),it will count it as 4 days but really it is suppose to count it as 2 days...

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make some assumptions on your data structure based upon your query. It seems that you're only using the `Orders` table for the `OrderID`, this is also in `OrderDetails`. I'm assuming that it is a `datetime` field as you're using this in your `datepart` function.

I think the particular issue you're having with counting the days multiple times could be resolved with a `count distinct` as I've used below.

This is your original query, slightly modified (untested as there is no sample data to work with)

```
SELECT 
i.name
,od.price
,SUM(od.Quantity) / COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(d,o.OrderDate))
FROM orderdetails od
JOIN orders o 
    ON o.orderid = od.orderid
JOIN item i 
    ON i.itemid = od.itemid
GROUP BY i.name, od.price
ORDER BY i.name
```

Ok, below is my explanation of this and test data.

Test Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#OrderDetails') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #OrderDetails
GO
CREATE TABLE #OrderDetails (OrderID datetime, itemID int, Price money, Quantity int)
INSERT INTO #OrderDetails (OrderID, ItemID, Price, Quantity)
VALUES
 ('2016-07-07 09:00:00', 1, 2.9, 10)
,('2016-07-07 09:30:00', 1, 3.0, 6)
,('2016-07-07 10:50:00', 1, 3.2, 2)
,('2016-07-07 09:00:00', 1, 2.8, 9)
,('2016-07-08 09:00:00', 1, 3.1, 8)
,('2016-07-08 12:30:00', 1, 3.0, 20)
,('2016-07-08 15:52:00', 1, 2.9, 15)
,('2016-07-09 15:52:00', 1, 2.9, 15)
,('2016-07-10 15:52:00', 1, 2.9, 15)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Item') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Item
GO
CREATE TABLE #Item (itemID int, Name varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Item (itemID, Name)
VALUES
(1,'Potatoes')
```

Query

```
SELECT
 i.Name Item_Name
,od.Price
,COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(date,od.OrderID)) UniqueDays
,SUM(od.Quantity)/COUNT(DISTINCT CONVERT(date,od.OrderID)) AvgSalesPerDay
FROM #OrderDetails od
JOIN #Item i
    ON od.itemID = i.itemID
GROUP BY
    i.Name
    ,od.Price
```

Result

```
Item_Name   Price   UniqueDays  AvgSalesPerDay
Potatoes    2.80    1           9
Potatoes    2.90    2           27
Potatoes    3.00    2           13
Potatoes    3.10    1           8
Potatoes    3.20    1           2
```

Comment: My orderDetails table looks like this:orderID,itemID,Price,Quantity. My orders Table has the following fields:OrderID,OrderDate,DeliveryDaye,DeliveryAddress,LastModified. The order date is in the orders table. I don't know why but it calculates the avg for every day seperatly.

Comment: Could you add this information as an edit to your original question please?

Comment: @yehudisgrosz you're not using o.OrderDate in the select statement, you're using o.OrderID. I've just edited my answer, try out my modified version of your original code now and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks a billion! Now it works. I just didn't realize that i typed o.orderid instead of o.orderdate as you told me. It was a typing error and i just missed it every time...thanks!!!!

Comment: Excellent, it's often easier for a fresh pair of eyes to notice these things. Feel free to upvote any answers that have helped. Also, if you could mark one as the accepted answer it would be appreciated.

Comment: On the left you'll see the up and down vote arrows next to each answer with the current score of the post between them. Just below that there should be a little tick that you can click for the accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/tour